# What does the word 「ばあ」mean?

Tags: words, contractions, role-language

It is highlighted in the bold part of the below sentence.

> さいきんじゃドヤ街【がい】のがきらをぞろぞろひきつれてそのへん**ばあ**ねり歩【ある】いてよ。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「ばあ」 is a colloquial contraction for 「をば」.  It is occasionally used in fiction, children's stories, etc. to show that the speaker is an older person from the country side.

In meaning and nuance, 「ばあ」＝「をば」＝ an emphatic 「を」

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%92%E3%81%B0-666115#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

「そのへん**ばあ**ねり歩いてよ」= "(someone) often walks around there"

Comment: I assume this is geographical variation? Where is this more common?

Comment: FYI, I've never actually heard any Japanese actually speak such an archaic dialect.  I'm in my 30s and from Shizuoka (80 km west of Tokyo)

Comment: Role language used in fiction is largely imaginary.  It transcends existing regions.

Comment: Read here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23690/what-do-the-words-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%8a%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b%e3%81%ae-mean/23691#23691

Answer (score 3):

They use ば for the objective particle を in Kyushu dialect.

そのへんばあねり歩いて＝ そんへんばねり歩いて ＝ そのへんをねり歩あるいて

Answer (score 2):

The use of “ば” and “ば（あ）” like:

> その[辺]{へん}ば（あ）[練]{ね}り歩く - strut around over there
>   冗談ば（あ）[止]{や}めちょくれ。 - Stop joking.
>   そげんこつば（あ）言いよって。[拳骨]{げんこつ}ば（あ）食らわすぞ。 - How can you dare to say that to me? I’ll give you a punch.

is often observed in the north-western part (Fukuoka, Saga, and Nagasaki Prefectures) of Kyushu. It depends on the person and the situation whether you pronounce it "ば,” or drawl like "ばあ”.

It substitutes for “…は” or “…を”. Therefore “そげんこつば（あ）言いよってからに” means “そのようなことを言うなんて,” “冗談ば（あ）止めちょくれ” means “冗談を言わないでください.”

I’m from Oita Prefecture, Kyushu. We don’t use “ば” in such a way in Ohita. I don’t think people in the middle and southern part of Kyushu have such a colloquial idiosyncrasy, I mean, the use of “ば（あ）” in such a way.