# Is the をば particle combination an abbreviated version of XはXを?

Tags: particle-は, particle-を, dialects, archaic-language

As far as I know when the topic and the object are the same we drop the object from the sentence to avoid redundancy. For example the following sentence is not correct:

> ラーメン は もう ラーメン を 食べました。

Correctly:

> ラーメン は もう 食べました。

But when I surfed on the internet I saw the をば combination which seems another way to avoid redundancy.

> ラーメン をば もう 食べました。

My question is: **Is をば an abbreviated version of XはXを?** If yes then: **Is there a difference between the two correct sentences besides that をば is used in old Japanese and some dialects?**

Comment: Can you cite a source for 「ラーメン をば もう 食べました」? I don't think that's a natural locution, at least not in modern Japanese.

Comment: Broadly, **no**, 「をば」 is not a contraction or abbreviation of 「XはXを」.  The ば here is indeed a form of は, but it is used as a kind of emphasis.  Consider 「に」 versus 「には」, 「と」 versus 「とは」, 「へ」 versus 「へは」, etc.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi
I now find a wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particles_of_the_Kagoshima_dialects which say: "The particle をば oba or ば ba marks a topicalized direct object."
Then what is mean the topicalized direct object?

Comment: @EddieKal I didn't save the page where I found the をば.

Comment: It's not that you **drop** the direct object to avoid redundancy. You turn it into the topic by changing the particle. ラーメンは in your sentence is also such a *topicalized* direct object.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23875/what-does-the-word-%e3%81%b0%e3%81%82-mean/23878#23878

Comment: Okay, I accept what you say. So the をば is just emphasis version of を and does not mark both topic and object in the same time.