# Usage of じゃ in 西瓜を買うと、俺もあいつも好きじゃで両得じゃ

Tags: dialects, copula, role-language

> 西瓜を買うと、俺もあいつも好きじゃで両得じゃ。

じゃ means then, well then. But what does じゃ in the above context? Seems the definition of then, well then can't fit in this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This じゃ is a dialectal copula (linking verb) which is used instead of だ. This じゃ is actively used in some areas of western Japan (especially in Hiroshima), but it's [also known as a typical role word of old men](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23690/5010). You will also see じゃから instead of だから, じゃが instead of だが, じゃった instead of だった, and so on. じゃあ in modern standard Japanese is totally different.

> 西瓜を買うと、俺もあいつも好きじゃで両得じゃ。
>   ≒ 西瓜を買うと、俺もあいつも好きだで、両得だ。
>   If I bought a watermelon, both he and I like it, so it would be win-win.

で after a clause can sometimes denote a cause or a reason.

Comment: 「だで」も方言（共通語にはそういう用法はない）という点も書いておいた方がいいのではないでしょうか…

Comment: @broccoliforest 「安い旨いで大満足」「トラブルだ延期だでもう大変」と似たような、終止形に続く接続助詞としての「で」の例は、方言じゃなくてもある気がします。「俺がやるだで見ててけろ」みたいな「だで」は方言だと思いますが。（しっくりくる既存の解説を探したのですが見つかりませんでした）

Comment: 確かに、そういう解釈もあるかもしれませんね…個人的には、「だで／じゃで」で「だから」の意味を表す方言と取った方が自然だと思いました（cf. [weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A7)）。これは「あかんで」のような終助詞とは異なります。

Comment: [こっち](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8D%E5%8F%A4%E5%B1%8B%E5%BC%81#%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E)ですか。単独で「俺も好きだで両得だ」ならとても方言ぽいですが、「俺も好きだ、あいつも好きだで、両得だ」なら標準語でも言いそうな気がします。この場合どっちなのか微妙ですが…