# What is the meaning of the slang ～じゃてえ?

Tags: meaning, expressions, dialects, role-language

I'd like to know what ～じゃてえ exactly means when located at the end of verbs and/or adjectives. Do young people use it rhetorically?

The whole sentence is:

> なのにのう ズイブンじゃてえ

Comment: Do you have a full sentence with it? Could it possibly be ～じゃねえ? There's also the possibility it's a dialectal variant of ～だって, or you're mishearing ～じゃで, which would be a dialectal variant of ～だよ.

Comment: thank you for answering！the whole sentence was なのにのう ズイブンじゃてえ. it was written so i didnt mishear it. im familiar with じゃねえ but じゃてえ is new to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a recent slang word but a dialectal form of だって or だな. It's probably still in use in some parts of western Japan<sup>*</sup>, but it may be best to consider it as [a stereotyped role word of old people and people in rural areas](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23690/5010).

<sub>* Both のう and じゃ are actively used in reality in [Setouchi region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setouchi_Region). Some source say じゃて(え) is Okayama dialect.</sub>