# Meaning of "noun+じゃのう "

Tags: meaning

Please explain what "noun+じゃのう " means in

> わあ　カワイイ。 小さい車 じゃのう

Comment: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/7013927

Comment: Related/Duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34196/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62717/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12106/9831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might depend on where this is coming from, but in Hiroshima this is part of the local dialect used by the older generation. じゃ equivalent to だ and のう equivalent to ね.